# Why can magic users only expel excess magical energy via sexual means?

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems, sex

I am developing a unique magical system for my world, and I’ve introduced a concept involving magic users, *Fjǫlkunnugir*, who possess the extraordinary ability to manipulate mystical energies called *safti*. *Safti* is a life force, a kind of *“bioelectricity”* accumulating, pulsating in and through all living things from a life source called Yggdrasil.

However, there’s a crucial caveat attached to their magical prowess – the need to expel excess *safti* through sexual means, such as masturbation or intercourse. This aspect has the side effect of giving *Fjǫlkunnugir* high sex drives and making them very easy to arousal via sexual means. Failure to do so can result in severe consequences, ranging from debilitating weakness to death.

How do I justify this aspect?

Comment: Just like sneezing where your intrathoracic pressure increases and after you have expelled the foreign matters the heart rate will resume it's normal rhythm but in your case it's the magic version. But should you try to hold it back...

Comment: ...just don't? As the author, you have the freedom to just make things the way you want them to be. Nobody's gonna stop you. If you want your magical system horny, just make it so. In fact, I would argue that over-justification is the death of many "worldbuilding" attempts because if you leave things open, it can be up to the reader to interpret, but if you try to build it out to the last detail, you just give critics more potential "points of failure" to attack.

Comment: An unintentional side-effect is that you've just created a justification for the trope of "good people look good" and "evil people look ugly". If someone is good, they'll seek willing partners, and thus looking physically appealing is worth the effort. If, on the other hand, someone decides they're satisfied with unwilling partners, they won't care what they look like since they're not concerned about being physically attractive to their victims.

Comment: It's magic! Why do you need to justify it? This is just how it works!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Safti is a life force

Sex is needed to generate life. Like the jokes go "sex is hereditary. If your parents didn't have it, you won't have it either".

It doesn't take a peer of Aristotle to close the syllogism and conclude that sex in linked to Safti and that by sexual means you can control the amount of Safti in your body.

It's not a new concept. In some Asian cultures it was common practice for farmers to store seeds under their bed, so that the vital energy released during the sexual act would be captured by the seeds and make good to them, rather than be absorbed by some less benign creature.

Answer (score 4):

Magical energy (many game systems call it "mana points") accumulates in (some?) living beings for some reason. It may also accumulate in magical artifacts, but that's a different mechanic. Unspent, excess magical energy is harmful to the being.

Using magical energy "for effect" requires the highly focussed effort of a highly trained mind. Without this effort, there will be "side effects" which may be harmful, or just disturbing. (Innocent bystanders being followed by a swarm of illusion butterflies when the magical entertainer leaks energy?)

Why not *use* it all for some nifty spell? Well, there is the effort to do it right, and the side effects mentioned above. Mages do not cast spells lightly.

To *dissipate* magical energy without *any* side effects requires the **exact opposite of that mental state** in a caster. Pure bliss and self-abandonment. Some magical adepts reach this state through physical extertion, similar to a [runner's high](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurobiological_effects_of_physical_exercise). For some, it may even be a [berserker's fury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker). But that may damage the furniture if there is no foe to fight. So **most** magical adepts reach the mental state through sex.